# Implications of $\|Ax\|_1\leq \|Bx\|_1$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let us assume that $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $\|\cdot\|_1$ is the (vector) norm-1 defined as $\|x\|_1=\sum_{i=1}^n|x(i)|$, and the induced matrix norm is $\|A\|_1=\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Ax\|_1}{\|x\|_1}=\sup_{\|x\|_1=1}\|Ax\|_1$. Let us assume that:

$$
\|Ax\|_1 \leq \|Bx\|_1, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n.
$$

What does this imply about $A$ and $B$? I can only tell that if $n=m$ and $B$ is invertible then we may set $y=Bx$ so $x=B^{-1}y$, hence the above inequality becomes:

$$
\|AB^{-1}y\|_1 \leq \|y\|_1, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n,
$$

Therefore,

$$
\|AB^{-1}\|_{1}\leq 1.
$$

But, I would be interested in the case where $B$ is not assumed to be invertible and may also not be a square matrix.

**Update:** Take $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $x\neq 0$, then $\|x\|_1>0$, so
$$
\frac{\|Ax\|_1}{\|x\|_1}\leq\frac{\|Bx\|_1}{\|x\|_1},
$$
and taking the supremum over all $x\neq 0$ we get 
$$
\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Ax\|_1}{\|x\|_1}\leq\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Bx\|_1}{\|x\|_1} \Rightarrow\|A\|_1\leq\|B\|_1.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non-invertible case does not differ much from the invertible case. By a similar argument to yours, we have $\|AB^+y\|_1\le\|y\|_1$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}^m$, where $B^+$ denotes the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $B$. Hence $\|AB^+\|_1\le1$.